# reactJS rendering empty data

Tags: reactjs, rendering

When I am fetching the data I want them to fetch first and then render. It always renders empty string even when I'm setting the state and I don't understand why.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = {
      view: 'feed',
      posts: '' //data I want to render
    }

    this.changeView = this.changeView.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.getAllPosts() //getting the data
  }

  getAllPosts () {
    axios.get('/api/blogs')
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
        this.setState({
          posts: response
        })
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }

  changeView(option) {
    this.setState({
      view: option
    })
  }

  renderView () {
    const {view} = this.state

    if (view === 'feed') {
      return <Feed blogs={this.state.posts}  handleClick={() => 
this.changeView('anypostview')}/> //passing data as props in Feed blogs
    } else {
      return <Post />
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="nav">
          <span className="logo"
            onClick={() => this.changeView('feed')}>
            BLOGMODO
          </span>
          <span className={this.state.view === 'feed'
            ? 'nav-selected'
            : 'nav-unselected'}
            onClick={() => this.changeView('feed')}>
            See all Posts
          </span>
          <span className="nav-unselected">
            Write a Post
          </span>
          <span className="nav-unselected">
            Admin
          </span>
        </div>

        <div className="main">
          {this.renderView()}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

When I'm loging the data in my Feed component I first see an empty string and then it logs the fetched data. How can I prevent it from rendering an empty string and waiting for data to be fetched first and then rendering it?

Comment: Just check if it's an empty string and return null? I would actually set the initial state to an array for consistency and check length.

Comment: A component can't delay its own rendering. If the component is the top level component you need to fetch the data first and only then render the react DOM. If it is a child the parent component needs to fetch first and only render the child when the data is available. The alternative is to indicate loading (e.g. a spinner) while the request did not finish.

Comment: I tried it with an array but would get the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within `render`, check if `posts` state is populate or not.
If not, show a loading screen or gif.

When `posts` is populated, and then you will see rendered posts.

```js
render() {
  const {posts} = this.state;
  if (!posts || posts.length <= 0) {
    // Display a message or Show a Loading Gif here
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  }

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="nav">
          ...
        </div>

        <div className="main">
          {this.renderView()}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helped!

Comment: @LukasLukeStateczny You're welcome there. And would you mark it as an answer if it has solved the issue?